# Unable to do 'data-store' or 'table' operation in Zoho Catalyst (Python SDK), in this particular code, getting table metadata

Tags: python, zoho, catalystbyzoho

I am trying to learn Zoho Catalyst using Python SDK. However, I am stuck when trying to do operations in 'data-store' or 'table' of the Catalyst environment.

Error I get:

> {
> "error": "Error while fetching table metadata: {'code': 'UNPARSABLE_RESPONSE', 'message': 'unable to parse the response json'}"
> }

Am i doing something completely wrong, or are there any other alternative code for this?

I tried the following code and was expecting to read the metadata of one of my tables in the server.

```
import logging
from flask import Request, make_response, jsonify
import zcatalyst_sdk

def handler(request: Request):
    app = zcatalyst_sdk.initialize()
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    if request.path == "/":
        response = make_response(jsonify({
            'status': 'success',
            'message': 'Hello from main.py'
        }), 200)
        return response
    elif request.path == "/cache":
        default_segment = app.cache().segment()

        insert_resp = default_segment.put('Name', 'DefaultName')
        logger.info('Inserted cache: ' + str(insert_resp))
        get_resp = default_segment.get('Name')

        return jsonify(get_resp), 200
    elif request.path == "/get_table_metadata":
        try:
            # Create a Data Store component instance
            datastore_service = app.datastore()

            # Specify the table ID
            table_id = 5249000000011745  # Replace with your specific table ID

            # Get the metadata of the specified table
            table_metadata = datastore_service.get_table_details(table_id)

            # Return the table metadata as JSON response
            return jsonify(table_metadata), 200
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = f"Error while fetching table metadata: {e}"
            logger.error(error_message)
            response = make_response(jsonify({
                'error': error_message
            }), 500)
            return response
    else:
        response = make_response('Unknown path')
        response.status_code = 400
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in the code you provided, the table instance and datastore instance were not initialized correctly from the catalyst object. This may have resulted in an error in your function code.

To address this issue, I followed a simple web application tutorial [linked here](https://docs.catalyst.zoho.com/en/tutorials/alien-city/python/introduction/) and referenced the tutorial's function code to ensure that the datastore and table instances were initialized properly.